# How to make a button.onClick animation like the youtube's play/pause animation in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have no idea how to make this kind of an animation in android studio. Please help me out.

This is how I want it to be I mean like the Youtube animation.

**By the animation I don't mean the one in which play icon changes to pause icon, I mean the white thing that appears just like this**

[Please see this for more info](https://youtu.be/ocwUSdhyHqI)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got exactly what you mean but I guess you are looking for drawable animation which change between slices of photos like animation

see the following link : [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation#:~:text=One%20way%20to%20animate%20Drawables,the%20basis%20for%20Drawable%20animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation#:%7E:text=One%20way%20to%20animate%20Drawables,the%20basis%20for%20Drawable%20animations).

and if you give more information about your code to help you better.